# A current of 1A flows in a wire carried by electrons. How many electrons pass through the a cross-section of the wire each second?

Tags: current

> A current of 1A flows in a wire carried by electrons. How many electrons pass through the a cross-section of the wire each second?

This is a quite simple but really difficult question to me right now, and I put this as the heading because it is one of the most basics of questions.

So the charge of an electron is -1.6 x 10^(-19) C. If we look at the definition of what current is, it is the rate at which charge is moving.

But how are we supposed to find the number of electrons, without any other information?

Comment: What do you know about the definition of an amp?

Comment: @BrianDrummond One Amp is the current that flows with electric charge of one Coulomb per second. I=Q/t.

Comment: So you know how many coulombs per second. Now, how many electrons make a Coulomb?

Comment: @BrianDrummond Thanks alot Brian :) I answered my own question you can see it under the Answers :) I understood.

Answer (score 3):

**I solved my own Question**

$$Q=It$$

Since I=1A and we are interested when t=1 second. Therefore:

$$Q=1\cdot 1=1C$$

We know that the charge of 1 electron has the magnitude 1.6 x 10^(-19) C. Therefore we are looking for the solution to this equation:

$$\text{# Number of electrons x }1.6 \text{ x }10^{-19}=1C$$

$$\implies \text{Number of electrons}=6.25 \text{ x } 10^{18}$$

Comment: ...and how much spaces occupies one ampere?

Comment: @GRTech how much space? Ummm no idea.

Answer (score 1):

> So the charge of an electron is -1.6 x 10^(-19) C. If we look at the
>   definition of what current is, it is the rate at which charge is
>   moving.

The current is the variation in the amount of charge vs. time, not the speed at which the load moves.
If you know the current, you can know how much power is transferred per unit time.
**TIP**: make an analysis of the dimensions and units.

The current can be defined as

\$
i(t) = \dfrac{dq(t)}{dt}
\$

that is, it is the variation of the charge \$q\$, with respect to time.
If we consider the cross section of a conductor, the variation of charge corresponds to the amount of charge passing through that surface.

Comment: Isn't Q=It, so therefore I=Q/t? What I meant by moving is rate of flow of charge.

Comment: @M.S.E look at the edit append to my answer.

Comment: But isn't this exactly the same thing as what I said :( I still don't understand how this leads to an answer.

Comment: Suppose you have 100 kg of water flowing through a pipe each minute. How would you figure out how many liters that is?

Comment: @ThePhoton Doesnt it depend on the duration. it would be 100L in one minute, 200L in two minutes, etc etc. So clearly the amount of litres depend on the time.

Comment: @M.S.E Your proposal is properly formulated, I just gave him a little more _formality_. Try dimensional analysis. Check the definition of Ampere as current measuring unit: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampere

Comment: Oh I solved it :D

Comment: +1 for helping me out :) Thanks alot. I have answered my own question :)